# Flutter Routes get return black screen

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-navigation

My Route is main  -> Screen 1 -> Screen 2-> Tab Screen

Tab Screen Contain Two Tab :

Tab1 , Tab2

How can jump to Screen 1 on using submit button in Tab1 ?

Navigator.of(context)
.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil

(TabScreen.routeName,

ModalRoute.withName

(Screen1.routerName));

it's Show me a Black Screen After I navigate to Screen1
and after i back press exit to app

Comment: Please add some code, which justifies the above statement, so that community can help

Answer (score 0):

You can use named routes and popUntil:

```
    Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.settings.name == 'screen_1');
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions and the one you tried will require to name the routes first  at the top level of your widget tree.

By your explanation I am guessing that on Navigator.pop() from tab screen, you will get the Screen2 page. In this case you can just call Navigator.pop() twice after submit button is pressed.

Comment: i call pop() pop() but same result

Comment: In that case you should probably recheck your widget tree. Black screen appears when the is no page left in the stack (basically when you pop out the only page left in the stack).

Comment: Mainpage->FirstPage->SecondPage->ThirdPage->ForthPage Contain 2 Tab Tab1,Tab2
on tab have submit button on submit button i want to move SecondPage but i user above navigation so on click submit i only visible black screen.